# Functions and events in javascript and Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/wrJKm/3/), if you click on the rectangle you'll see the "Hello" alert, however the variable x belongs to the function f(), not to the event handler mousedown. Is this code correct?

The HTML:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 600, 600); 

    var r = paper.rect(100,100, 200,200);

    r.attr({ "fill" : "#000000"});

    f();

    function f(){

        var x = "Hello";

        r.mousedown(function(e) {   
            alert ( x );
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of your question, but yes, the mousedown function can see the variable declared in the parent function because javascript supports Lexical scoping: that is, the scope of a variable is defined by its location within the source code.

Javascript supports the notion of closures. "A function defined in a closure 'remembers' the environment in which it was created". Effectively the mousedown function contains a reference to the variable x declared in the function f().

If you're coming from a language which has block scope this can be confusing at first.

if you were to change your function f() to read:

```
function f() {
    var x = "Hello";
    r.mousedown(function(e) {
        alert(x);
    });
    x = "Goodbye";
}
```

clicking the rectangle will display "Goodbye" - the variable x that the mousedown function sees is that which was declared in f();

for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures